# selecting rows from postgres using sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm trying to connect to my postgres database and do a select statement.The code is given below.

I get a error saying table1 is undefined...Table1 is in the database..how table1 will be recognized in my code.

code.py

```
engine1 = create_engine('postgresql://username:password@localhost/testdb')

Session1 = sessionmaker(bind=engine1)
session1 = Session1()

for each in session1.query(table1).all():
    print each
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you can query for `table1` you need to define it and its mapping. Following should get you on the right track:

```py
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine1)
table1 = Table('Table1', metadata, autoload=True)
# now you can run the query
```

*Reading [SQL Expression Language Tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/tutorial.html) is highly recommended.*